# Excel VBA With PDF Viewer

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a form that has the "Adobe PDF Reader" additional controls on it, a button and a text box.

The only code I have is on the button that is:

```
PDFViewer.src = textbox1.text
```

This excel file and macro works on my computer but when someone else tries to open the macro they get the following error message:

> "System error &H80004005 (-2147467259). unspecified error"

I don't know why I am getting this error when it works fine on my computer.

Thanks

Comment: Has PDF Viewer been created on the other machine?  Check something else from its properties.

Comment: both computers have the same pdf reader 11 and everything. I just put the excel file on a usb and transferred it to the other computer and tried running it and I get that error message.

Comment: Is the control present as desired in design mode of the form? and is the file available to both

Comment: yes, the form and the other controls are all fine. the file location and file is available for both computers. I was doing some research and I saw that google chrome could affect this activeX additional PDF viewer control. Not sure if this is the problem but the first computer I have does not have chrome while the second computer does.